# GET 500 (Internal Server Error) laravel/js

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous, laravel-5

I'm trying to send an OTP to a user when the user clicks the button.

so I'm using LARAVEL And I'm returning the response as `JSON`.

When I click the button I get this error in console :

> GET http://domain/resend 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I read a question about the same topic the answer said that I have to add CSRF token, I did add it I still get the error.

my js code :

```
try {
        let resend = await fetch('http://domain/resend',{
            method:'GET',
            headers:{

                'Content-type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content').value
            },
        });
        let resultre = await resend.json();

        return {

            resultre
        }
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

And im returning the laravel reponse :

```
return response()->json($user->save());
```

I'm still beginner So my code might not be good,

thank you

Comment: 500 is server error. Look for apache/nginx logs, php error log or storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: there is no error for apache/nginx

Comment: @FelippeDuarte is right that 500 means server or backend error. I think there are a couple possibilities -- your htaccess file in the project root might need to be changed, or your apache server might have connection error messages (Felippe's idea - that your page isn't being served), or it might be your routes, too. Would you mind posting the results of this command from the command line?   *** php artisan route:list  ***

Comment: @RoboBear  GET|HEAD | resend    | resendsms  |App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@resendsms| web,auth,phone  

 thats the route im trying to use

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` - that usually means that the response is not JSON, but probably an error message in HTML format.  You should read it!

Comment: @James That makes sense! because now I get the error Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0  only without the 500 error 
But I'm already returning JSON? I'm confused

Comment: That's the error that Javascript is throwing because it can't read the response, however the response itself contains a different error, which causes the JS parsing error - that's the one you should check out (the server response before JS tries to do anything with it).

Comment: @James oh great thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

This is server side related issue. Since your server outputs debug error code, probably in HTML, it is not valid JSON output and your Javascript code cannot parse it as JSON.

That means the error is probably related with the method being called via route where you have this portion of code:

```
return response()->json($user->save());
```

At first glance, it looks like you are trying to call save() method on null. Is your $user object missing? Try to get it from $request.

But still, you need to check your logs. 
You should set your application to debug mode, in .env file.

Then you should check the logs ( if monolog is not installed, install it ) 
Check more for Logging in Laravel here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging

Maybe it would be helpful to wrap your response in try catch block to see what error throws:

```
try{
    return response()->json($user->save());
}catch(\Exception $e){
    return response()->json(['error'=>$e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Comment: the $user object is not empty or missing ,, I tried to change the reponse and i get : {"success":"sent"} which is valid response but i still get the error

Comment: @Mcpartland, I think that your error is caused because you try to return save() method, that probably throws error. Try to wrap it using try catch block

Comment: I didn't get any kind of errors :\ , it returns `true`